# How do I migrate a question? Or should I close it?

Tags: discussion

Recently I asked a question on Stack Overflow in regards to a [bug I found in the cmd.exe batch parsing engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284131/cmd-exe-parsing-bug-leads-to-other-exploits?noredirect=1#comment36351320_23284131). Long story short it can cause a stack overflow (due to infinite recursion) or a memory leak because of the bug 'restarting' the parsing without failing properly. As I pointed in the question and the comments (and the 1 answer) have said, it does involve a user running the malformed script (i.e. social engineering) so if that can be done then the user already has bigger security concerns.

After a little more research, however, I do have more security questions in regards to this, like could a [heap spray](http://www.vupen.com/blog/20120710.Advanced_Exploitation_of_Internet_Explorer_HeapOv_CVE-2012-1876.php) type of 'attack' be used in conjunction with this which would bypass DEP and ASLR. To this end I don't think I'll get an answer I'm looking for (something other than 'it's not exploitable because the user would have to run it') on Stack Overflow; as well I agree with some of the comments that the question is no longer an 'appropriate' question for Stack Overflow.

I think the [InfoSec StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) could help in pointing out some more research articles I could read with regards to this question but I'm unsure if I should migrate it (some how?) or if I should close the current question and possibly ask a more concise question linking to it on the InfoSec Q&A site?

Thanks for any help

Comment: First, we need to decide whether the question is on-topic for Stack Overflow. Clearly I think it is, [I was the first person who voted to re-open it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23284131/revisions). I don't understand why people think it is *not* on-topic. I'm interested to hear some of the rationales. But that question's comments thread is not an appropriate place to have those discussions. It is already too long for my attention span.

Comment: That post is ~4000 words long. Where is the actual *question*? It feels more like a personal blog post to me.