# How do I migrate a post from Android Enthusiasts to SO?

Tags: support, migration

I have gone through this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256836/how-do-i-migrate-a-question-or-should-i-close-it) but as its not clear I am asking a different question here.

Here is a [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/75708/android-gestureimageview-image-uri) which is completely off-topic. Its having blocks of code and doesn't suit the Android Enthusiasts SE (i.e. site for problems with Android devices). It is best suited for Stack Overflow; can I migrate this post to Stack Overflow? If yes then how, if no then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flag a post as "off-topic: belongs on another Stack Exchange" site. In the dialog you get, you select "Close for another reason" and then "Off-topic".

However, that dialog does not always show the site that a question should go to - only the 5 most likely sites for migrations are mentioned here.
So if the site where the question should be migrated to is not mentioned, use a custom flag and explain the problem.

Once you've raised a flag, it's up to the moderators. Common users cannot migrate questions, only mods can.

**However** before asking to migrate a question, consider if the question is good enough for Stack Exchange at all! One of our most important guidelines with respect to migrations is: "We don't migrate crap."

Comment: Well I wouldn't call the specific question *crap*... The code could probably be trimmed down, but there are much worse questions asked all the time.

Comment: @user000001 I wanted my answer to be general. I haven't looked at that particular question in depth, but at a quick glance it looks OK. Not even a lot of code, especially for an Android question.