# Customize "Belongs on another SE site"

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

We currently have 5 sites to mark that a question belongs somewhere else for migration...

[image]

and I know [we have metrics to determine which sites to show](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250056/off-topic-close-reasons) based on migration statistics.

Sure you [can flag as "Other"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262826/how-do-i-migrate-a-post-from-android-enthusiasts-to-so/262831#262831) but is that really the best option if another is available?

Could the "Migration" dialog have at least one "empty" link that we could customize to hold a link to whatever SE site benefits us most? This may not revolutionize the site but it would make closing a little quicker.

For example, superuser is the only one in the list that I personally get a chance to use much. But [android enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) is more used by me since I spend most of my time in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Now, this might not be the best idea as it could cause more unnecessary work in migration land if these usually won't be migrated. But I don't know 100% how that works regarding if the question would really be on-topic there. If this is the case, then maybe a customizeable link on the dialog before in "Off-topic"?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce that is very similar but [it's target](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) would probably be better since this isn't *just* referring to migration though that was my first thought.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260917/1380752) was more towards my second idea which doesn't include migration but its only responses were regarding migration, it seems.